# Encountered something abnormal while working on a derivative problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

Why is Method 1 not working if Method 2 is working?

How can I proceed with the first method?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please use Mathjax to format your questions. It makes them more readable. [Here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method one does work; you just need to keep going!

\begin{align*}
y_3 &= \frac{-2c((cx+d)y_2)-y_1c)}{(cx+d)^2}\\
&= \frac{-2c(cx+d)y_2}{(cx+d)^2}+\frac{2c^2y_1}{(cx+d)^2}\\
&= \frac{-2cy_2}{cx+d}-\frac{cy_2}{cx+d}\\
&= -\frac{3cy_2}{cx+d},
\end{align*}
and then multiply by $2y_1$ to get
$$2y_1y_3 = -\frac{6cy_1y_2}{cx+d} = 3y_2^2$$
as desired.